Is there a way to make a folder *act* as the top level directory to a program?
So basically imagine we normally have a setup like this:
/main/
/main/config/
/main/config/config.json

And say I have a program which is expecting to access the config in config.json.
Is there any way to convince the program that a different folder is the top level directory? Like say we instead placed this file structure in a test folder.
/test/main/config/config.json

If our program is expecting absolute paths, is there any way we can make it resolve to that path?

man chroot and Basic Chroot.

Or better yet, read amount mount namespaces.

Maybe a sandbox?
